# Why is #+ used for multiline comments in the Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide

Tags: bash, coding-style, comments

I noticed in the [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html), that multiline comments are denoted as `#+` rather than simply `#`. E.g. [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/varsubn.html#EX9).

(there is also a `#%` used in that particular example, denoting something like a bullet list(?), but this is literally the only location in the document where this is used, whereas the `#+` syntax is used extensively)

I was wondering if this is some sort of convention, or if there is a particular reason for it other than the fact it just looks nice.

I note that it specifically seems to denote lines that are meant to be a continuation on a single line, rather than multi-line comments in general, so I'm wondering if it was simply done internally for parsing / documentation generation.

Has anyone else encountered this out in the wild before? Does anyone actually use this style?

Comment: Huh. First time I've seen this. I don't think it has an actual meaning in the code, it looks more like a convention to me. Maybe some code highlighting tool can make use of this.

Comment: The ABS is not a good reference. If I were you I would erase it from my computer. There are other good resources, e.g., there are many good ones given in the [Bash tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info).

Comment: That convention reminds me of Fortran with its continuation lines marked by a character other than blank or zero in column 6.  It isn't something I've ever seen or used.  If anything, I'd use pseudo-bullets to mark the start of a comment and leave that off the continuation lines: `# - First line of` — `#   several`.

Comment: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html#COMMENTH

Comment: Thanks @choroba, I hadn't seen that. I guess that answers that.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf interesting, why do you say this? This is even more surprising to me when it's a tldp resource! It seems to be [well regarded](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/12053/229444) elsewhere on the site. Is it considered to be a more 'hacky' resource?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I don't agree with your comment either since I learned a lot from ABS but seems you [may have a point](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/tutoriallist).

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou well, there are lots of bad things in this guide. Just for fun I went [to a random page](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html#FUNCTIONS), and Example 24-1 shows bad practice: upper case variable names, unquoted variables expansions, use of `[` instead of `[[`, and (horror!) use of `let`, and why on Earth do they use `exit $?` at the end of the script?

Comment: @LuisMuñoz and on the freenode #bash channel, [it's been disregarded since 2005…](http://wooledge.org/~greybot/meta/abs)

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf never late to learn something new ;-).